# How to add spaces when a number is followed by a letter in laravel

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this text in UTF-8

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-
```

as you can see, in `根３丁` there are no spaces, I would like it to end up being `根 ３ 丁` for example, the same with `-２V` and add spaces: `- ２ V`

As a final result, I am looking for the text to be

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根 ３ 丁目 １３- ２ V-
```

that is, adding spaces while there are no numbers next to it (for example that `１３-`, **it must remain the same**)

what I currently have removes all the numbers and adds a space to them

```
$string = preg_replace('/\d+/u', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Please read the documentation instead of asking frequently asked questions:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I believe this is a complex question about regex and just mistagged.  It is only tangentially related to laravel or php because that is the language of execution, but the difficult part is devising a regex (or alternate method) that does what he wants.

Comment: Would `preg_replace('/(\d+)/u', ' $1 ', $string)` not work here?

Answer (score 3):

You can use groups in your regex pattern replacement.

- Group 1: `(\p{L}|\-)`. Any letter or `-`
- Group 2: `(\d+)`. Any number(s)
- Group 3: `(\p{L}|\-)`. Any letter or `-`

```php
$string = preg_replace(
    '/(\p{L}|\-)(\d+)(\p{L}|\-)/u',  /* pattern */
    '${1} ${2} ${3}',                /* replacement */
    $string                          /* subject */
);
```

Comment: You're too fast, I'm typing it :(

Comment: Instead of `\p{L}|\-` write `[\pL-]`

Answer (score 2):

You could assert either a letter or `_` to the left and right of the digits, and replace with the full match surrounded by a space on both sides.

```
(?<=[-\p{L}])\d+(?=[\p{L}-])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1MpgmT/1)

Example

```
$s = "名古屋市北区,大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-";
$pattern = "/(?<=[-\p{L}])\d+(?=[\p{L}-])/u";

echo preg_replace($pattern, " $0 ", $s);
```

Output

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根 ３ 丁目 １３- ２ V-
```